# Where can I find out what games have cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

Which games drop cards?

I've been looking at the [Steam Trading Card FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq).  However, I recently discovered that it's incomplete *(eg. Trine 2 and A.R.E.S. now have cards, but aren't listed there)*.

Obviously I don't expect someone here to maintain an updated list; but, **is there *anywhere* online I can view an updated list of which games have cards?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Click here to view all games with Trading Cards!](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=29)

---

How to get there:

1. Go to the [Steam shop page](http://store.steampowered.com/) or open the Store in Steam itself.
2. Click on the search button (the magnifying glass in the top right).
3. A little below, on the right side there are categories to filter by.
4. Look for the category "Narrow by feature" and select "Steam Trading Cards"

[image]

Voilá, all games with trading cards :)

Comment: LOL, following my own advice, I realized that Super Meat Boy also has cards not ;)

Comment: I just came to that same realization - it's unfortunate that Steam Cloud apparently did not back up my save game T_T

Comment: Super Meat Boy doesn't have Steam Cloud synchronization. That's why I'm super paranoid with backuping all my savegames on a weekly basis.

Comment: No, it [definitely has cloud support](http://steamcommunity.com/app/40800/discussions/0/828923952230594176/).  It just didn't work.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Hm, didn't know that they added that, since they said they won't to it anymore, but the Steam store doesn't list cloud support at the moment, so ...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Thx for the edit, I just found that link reading the FAQ, too ;)

Comment: Whoa, they must have *just* added it to the FAQ, that wasn't there a few hours ago.  Maybe they are reading this thread, too :P

Comment: The interface has changed, I do not see "advanced search" anymore.

Comment: @Yrogirg You're right, it is now directly listed under "Narrow by feature". I will update the screenshot soon.

Answer (score 9):

You basically need to use a combination of the [Steam Trading Card FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq) in conjunction with the [Steam Trading Card Community Group announcements](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tradingcards). Over time the FAQ will get updated but for completely up to date information you will need to watch out for announcements.

For example, **at the time of writing** the support games as per the FAQ are as follows;

- Borderlands 2
- CS:GO
- Don't Starve
- Dota 2
- Half-Life 2
- Portal 2
- Team Fortress 2
- Left 4 Dead 2
- Sanctum 2
- Go Home Dinosaurs!
- Triple Town
- Cubemen 2
- Monster Loves You!
- Really Big Sky
- Faerie Solitaire
- BIT.TRIP RUNNER 2

In addition to these, the following games are listed in the Steam Trading Cards group announcements;

- Monaco
- A.R.E.S.
- Trine 2
- They Bleed Pixels
- Defender's Quest: Valley of the Forgotten
- FTL: Faster Than Light
- 1... 2... 3... KICK IT! (Drop That Beat Like an Ugly Baby)
- Strike Suit Infinity
- Zach Zero
- Tower Wars
- Serious Sam 3: BFE
- Anodyne
- Super Meat Boy
- Blocks That Matter
- Brütal Legend

To see a list of games that you own that have badge support, in Steam hover over your name in the Navigation bar and select Badges;

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Log in on steamcommunity.com or Steam itself
2. In the navigation bar you'll see a header with your steam display name. Hover it.
3. Click on Badges.

Comment: That only shows cards for games that I own *(and apparently only F2P games I play often?  I have played Dota 2 before and currently have it installed, but it doesn't show up in my list)*

Comment: You don't get Dota 2 drops because you haven't spent money in the in game store prior to the start of the Trading Cards beta. You can now get one drop every $9 spent there (!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a textual list of games with trading cards (one that you can subscribe to so you will get notifications via Steam if new games get trading cards as the creator of the list keeps it updated) [here](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tradingcards/discussions/1/864973981286575231/).