# Can I see cards for games I do not own?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I know I can go under my profile and click "Badges" and see all the cards for games I own as well as progress, etc.

Is there a way that I can see the cards for the games I do not own?  I know games with cards say so down by the `Single-player`, `Steam Achievements`, and other tags.  I also know I could search the Market for each game to see the cards users have put up.  But is there a place I can go to actually see the cards for games I have not purchased (or even just how many cards it has)?

Comment: The [Advanced Steam Store search](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120416/where-can-i-find-out-what-games-have-cards) will show you games with cards, but not how many cards, and not whether you own them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the cards, badges, emoticons and backgrounds can be viewed [on the **Steam Card Exchange** website](http://steamcardexchange.net/?showcase). Just find your game by its first letter.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the game's ID within Steam, yes you can.

I'll use my profile and 1,2,3 Kick-It as an example.  I do not own this game so it does not show up on my badge page.  In order to view the cards and my personal "progress," I looked it up in the steam store to find the ID:

> http://store.steampowered.com/app/15540/

The trailing number is the ID:  **15540**. I plugged this into the standard URL string for game card progress:

> http://steamcommunity.com/id/Topical_Decoy/gamecards/15540/

And now I can see all available cards.  This may be a bit of a roundabout way of doing it, but it's very effective. Just plug in your SteamID and you'll be good to go!

Comment: Hadn't thought about trying that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for [Total War: SHOGUN 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/201270/): steamcommunity.com/id/Topical_Decoy/gamecards/201270/

Comment: Very strange, it seems that the Total War: SHOGUN 2 ID is 34330 for game cards. If you plug that one into the Steam Store, it routes straight to 201270. Perhaps not completely foolproof if IDs are duplicated in the store DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a search on the marketplace with "appid:753" in it. This searches for all items associated with Steam itself, so a search along the lines of, say, [appid:753 borderlands 2](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=appid%3A753+borderlands+2) will find all Borderlands 2 items, be they cards, emoticons, backgrounds, etc. Refine it to [appid:753 borderlands 2 card](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=appid%3A753+borderlands+2+card) to reduce the results further. Or try [appid:753 card](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=appid%3A753+card) to see basically every card on Steam.

Also, if you have specific games you're after, you can just buy/trade for a card from them; this will cause the badge for those games to be tracked on the "Badges" page of your profile, same as any game you own.

Comment: Yes I knew the Marketplace method, but this is reliant of users that are actually selling the cards.  If it ends up where there are none of a specific card for sale, this will not give all of them.  Also, I wasn't really after making a badge or anything I just think the artwork on some are cool and wanted to look through the other games' cards.