# Can you see if a game has trading card support on its 'Library Page'?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

Right now on the Featured Items page of the store if a game has Card support it has a sash over the top left corner that says 'Cards'. On your profile, the badges section is a list of all your games that have badge/card support.

But at the moment I don't see anything on the game Library page in any of the 3 views (Detail, List, or Grid) that has any indication of card/badge support.

Is there an individual marker in any Library view (similar to the Cloud in List view that shows Steam Cloud support) to see if a game has trading card support?

Comment: Challenging a dupe shouldn't be part of the question; if you want to challenge it, either put it in the comments, or make a Meta post about it.

Comment: I don't quite agree that this is a duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120416/where-can-i-find-out-what-games-have-cards) since that question asked for a master list. I was curious if each game had an individual marker on the Library Page, which is not something that was directly mentioned in any of those answers. I knew there was a master list and acknowledged that but I am not asking for a master list.

Comment: Sorry it says 'edit this question to explain how it is different' so I figured it meant put it in the question.

Comment: Entirely understandable!  What it means by that is to edit the question to highlight the difference better.  Usually, if it gets closed as a dupe, that means the wording wasn't clear enough to focus on the specific area you're asking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot see if a game has Trading Card support from its Library page. If you want to see which of your games support Steam Trading cards, use the Badges section of your Profile that you mentioned. If you want to check a specific game you own, you're gonna have to look it up there, or just search around a bit.

Comment: The store page for each game will also tell you if it has badges (down where it says `Controller Support` and what-not)